# Crystal Server physical files

Tags: server, crystal-reports-server

we have installed SAP Crystal server in a MS Windows Server, it was formatted but we have all physical files of that SAP Crystal server.

Now we have installed a Crystal Server newly that same system but all .rpt file names are stored in a encrypted format. Is there any files which contains the original file name pointing this encrypted filename,

Answer (score 0):

Documents (such as Crystal Reports documents) are stored as two components:

- the **binary** component: i.e. the actual file, stored in the file repository.
- the **metadata**: all the data describing the binary file (e.g. the name, data sources it links to, user rights, etc). This data is stored in the central repository (CMS database).

Both parts complement each other and are **useless** by themselves.

What you have now is the binary component. It is not encrypted; the files are named using internal identifiers (CUID).

What you need is a proper export (e.g. in the form of a BIAR file) in order to transport documents properly from one environment to another. A BIAR file will contain both the binary and the metadata component.